# Need the (frequency dependent) dielectric permitivity of quartz

Tags: material-science, dielectric, absorption, microwaves

I have desperately googled to find a table or a graph for the complex dielectric permitivity of quartz (e.g. fused quartz), as a function of frequency, at room temperature. I am mostly interested in the imaginary component in the 0 - 15GHz range. Equivalently, a table or a graph of the loss tangent of the quartz as a function of the frequency would do.

Comment: Did you try Google Scholar or just Google? Or do you have access to an academic library (and the librarians within)?

Comment: I think I have tried both. I have no easy access to an academic library, but that's possible if someone provides me a book to look at.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to look for properties of "[fused silica](https://mo-sci.com/glass-101-fused-silica-vs-quartz/#:%7E:text=The%20terms%20%E2%80%9Cfused%20silica%E2%80%9D%20and,the%20quartz%20that%20was%20used.)", rather than "fused quartz":

> The terms “fused silica” and “fused quartz” are often used
> interchangeably. More accurately, “fused quartz” refers to an
> amorphous solid formed by melting naturally-occurring quartz. So,
> while fused silica is ostensibly pure SiO2, fused quartz contains
> impurities depending on the quartz that was used.

The reason is "fused silica" typically means high purity, whereas impurities can provide (arbitrarily?) high loss tangent.

So you may find the data on loss tangent of fused silica, [e.g.](https://www.dynasilfusedsilica.com/knowledge-base/)

```
            100 Hz    1 KHz     10 KHz    100 KHz   1 MHz    10 MHz 100 MHz 8.6 GHz 24 GHz
```

Loss Tangent    <.000004    <.000002    <.000005    0.00001 0.000015    0.00002 0.00003 0.00012 0.00033